file not found error in python .What should I do
I use this command and the file is in the specified location, but I encounter the following error. What should I do?
my code which it has the error
file_path = "C:/Users/user/Desktop/"
filename = "Extremely.Wicked.Shockingly.txt" 

the error is:
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\translation\translator\translate.py", line 13, in <module>
    with open(os.path.join(file_path, "Extremely.Wicked.Shockingly.srt"), "r") as f:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/user/Desktop/Extremely.Wicked.Shockingly.srt'


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You have "Extremely.Wicked.Shockingly.txt" in your code but "Extremely.Wicked.Shockingly.srt" (different file extension) in your error message. Could that be the source of the issue?

Yes, but I tried to test it in different ways, I changed it but it didn't work. i thought i had this bug because of the file extension .   actually i want to write a script to translate a subtitle in english to another language.
